# How to change font size in plot of cross-validation result from cvTools package in R?

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I try to manipulate size of fonts (title and axis labels, especially) in plot of cross-validation result from `cvTools` package in `R`. I am afraid it does not work:

```
library(cvTools)
data(coleman)
set.seed(1234) 

# Split n observations into K groups to be used for (repeated) K-fold cross-validation
folds <- cvFolds(nrow(coleman), K = 5, R = 50)

# perform cross-validation for an LS regression model
fitLm <- lm(Y ~ ., data = coleman)
cvFitLm <- cvLm(fitLm, cost = rtmspe, folds = folds, trim = 0.1)

# perform cross-validation for an MM regression model
fitLmrob <- lmrob(Y ~ ., data = coleman, k.max = 500)
cvFitLmrob <- cvLmrob(fitLmrob, cost = rtmspe, folds = folds, trim = 0.1)

# combine results into one object
cvFits <- cvSelect(LS = cvFitLm, MM = cvFitLmrob)
```

The two lines below differ in plot points size, but there is no change in title font size / labels font size.

```
# plot combined results
plot(cvFits, main = "foo_title")
plot(cvFits, main = "foo_title", cex = 0.5, cex.main = 0.5, cex.lab = 0.5)
```

What I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base graphics `par` settings generally don't work for lattice and other grid graphics. The plot methods for `cvTools` use lattice graphics. Here are ways to change the various font sizes in your plot:

```
  plot(cvFits, cex=0.5,                                  # Point markers
       main = list("foo_title", cex = 1),                # Title
       xlab=list(cex=0.75), ylab=list(cex=0.75),         # Axis titles
       scales=list(x=list(cex=0.75), y=list(cex=0.75)))  # Axis tick labels
```